# Calling function by triggering selectChange event Angular testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I started working on a small project in Angular(v4.0.0). In this project, I am adding unit testing. I read the [angular testing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing) and now have basic understanding of how to write unit testing in angular.

In this, I am struggling writing test case for a function which triggers on `selectChange` event from html.

**Code snippet of html**

```
html content
        <div class="metabs">
            <md-tab-group (selectChange)="selectMetabs($event)" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" *ngIf="!showAllMetabs">
                    <md-tab [label]="metab.name" *ngFor="let metab of dashboards"></md-tab>                        
            </md-tab-group>                    
        </div>
```

**code snippet of ts**

```
// Corresponding ts containing selectMetabs function

selectMetabs(event) {
  console.log("--in select metabos--");  // this console is not getting printed
  // rest of the code 
}
```

Now I wrote the test case for this which is:

```
describe('DashboardComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DashboardComponent>;
    let comp: DashboardComponent;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                DashboardComponent,
            ],
            providers: [
            ],
            imports: [
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                AppMaterialModule,
            ],
            schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
        }).compileComponents()
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent)
        comp = fixture.componentInstance
    }))

it("should check selectMetabs function call", async(() => {
    comp.showAllMetabs = false;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.metabs > md-tab-group'));
    let spy = spyOn(comp, 'selectMetabs');
    de.triggerEventHandler('selectChange', {index: 0});
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // pass test case
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // pass test case
    expect(comp.selectMetabolite).toHaveBeenCalledWith({index:0}); // pass test case
}))
```

These of my test cases is getting passed, which assures me that triggerEvent is working.

My confusion is that if `selectMetabs` function is getting called they why that console statement is not getting printed.

Also, this function is not getting covered in test coverage also.

I am not able to understand why this is happening. I am new to angular testing and this issue is confusing me. Please let me know if I am missing something or if I need to provide more info.

Useful suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that's happening is because you're mocking your component's `selectMetabs` method by `let spy = spyOn(comp, 'selectMetabs');`. And that's what you're testing as well.

This is very wrong as far as unit/integration tests are concerned. That's because, in a unit/integration test, you're not supposed to mock the methods of the **thing** under test(your component here). You should only be mocking the methods of the **other things** that your component is dependent on(a service's method for instance).

Once you remove this spy `let spy = spyOn(comp, 'selectMetabs');`, it should call your component's method and it should get covered.

**Now the question that arises is: What you should be expecting in that case?**

Well, you're doing `console.log("--in select metabos--");` in your component's `selectMetabs` method. So you can mock console.log and then expect it to have been called.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying back! I will check that once and will let u know!